# AWS Lambda and DynamoDB - updatetItem is not a function

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have this lambda function.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var sqs = new AWS.SQS({region : 'eu-west-1'});
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

var datetime = new Date().getTime().toString();

exports.handler = function(event, context) {

    dynamodb.updatetItem({
        "TableName": "tablename",
        "Item" : {
            "messageHash": {"S": hash },
            "date": {"S": String(datetime) }
        },
        "ReturnValues": "ALL_OLD"
    }, function(err, data) {
```

Any idea why every call ending with error "TypeError: dynamodb.updatetItem is not a function" ?? I think everything is right ... :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code.

dynamodb.update**t**Item -> dynamodb.updateItem

Answer (score 4):

I had to use: **dynamodb.update()**

Excerpts from AWS documentation:

> update(params, callback) ⇒ AWS.Request Edits an existing item's
>   attributes, or adds a new item to the table if it does not already
>   exist by delegating to AWS.DynamoDB.updateItem().

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html

Answer (score 0):

try this --->

```
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
```